# como pegar o valor selecionado no combobox (h:SelectOneMenu )?

Tags: ajax, jsf, combobox, xhtml

```html
<h:form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Categoria de Produto</label>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{produtoController.produto.categoriaProduto}" styleClass="form-control" style="width: auto">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione uma mesa" itemDisabled="false" />
      <f:selectItems value="#{produtoController.listaCategorias}" var="categoria" itemLabel="#{categoria.descricao}" itemValue="#{categoria}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Descrição do Produto</label>
    <h:inputTextarea value="#{produtoController.produto.descricao}" cols="80" rows="2" class="form-control" />
    <h6 class="help-block">Ex: Um hambúrgues, alface, tomate, milho, ovo, calabresa, bacon, catupiry</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Marca / Fornecedor</label>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{produtoController.produto.marca}" styleClass="form-control" style="width: auto" rendered="true">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione uma mesa" itemDisabled="false" />
      <f:selectItems value="#{produtoController.listaMarcas}" var="marca" itemLabel="#{marca.nomeMarca}" itemValue="#{marca}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <h:commandButton value="Cadastrar" action="#{produtoController.Salvar()}" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left: 5px" />
</h:form>
```

Não estou conseguindo pegar o valor dos combos. Se seleciono eles, não entra no método do h:commandButton. Mas se NÃO seleciono os combos, o método é executado.

Já testei com ValueChangeListener, p:ajax (usando o listener). Usando estes consigo somente capturar o primeiro selectOneMenu e executar o método do commandButton, mas o valor do segundo SelectOneMenu fica nulo :(

O que poderia ser?

Comment: Acontece algum erro ? Posta a sua classe ProdutoController.